# How to deploy flutter web on Heroku

Tags: flutter, web, heroku, deployment, server

I built a web application in Flutter and run the command `flutter build web` successfully. I'm trying to find a way to deploy it on Heroku like my react applications but found nothing in Heroku documentation.

Comment: Did you try creating a Procfile before deploying?

Comment: Here are some resources that will help you get started. https://medium.com/@agavitalis/how-to-deploy-a-simple-static-html-website-on-heroku-492697238e48 and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php

Comment: I hosted it on heroku by copying build/web folder to another folder named release and then adding it an index.php to the release folder and then creating a Procfile to point to the release folder. You can use any other language that heroku supports , does not have to be php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we run flutter web or static page run with the help of php.we can use many other language .we can simply use php without any more work.

First
create app in heroku  after this will shown .[image]

after run `flutter build web` in the root of the project folder it will generate static content in build/web .copy the file to any other directory and open cmd like this

[image]

create two file index.php and composer.json
in index.php
add this

```
<?php include_once("index.html");
```

in composer.json
add this (braces)

```
{}
```

[image]

after run the command in the

```
`heroku login`
heroku git:clone -a appname
git add .
git commit -am "make it better
git push heroku master
```

after running this it may be show any error .if not show any error
run this https://appname.herokuapp.com/#/ .your website will be live.

Answer (score 0):

Try these simple steps.
first, you need to create your app on Heroku, after typing the commands in your project directory console

1. heroku login
2. git init
3. heroku git:remote -a [your app name in heroku]
4. git commit -m "[your commit message]"
5. heroku buildpacks:set diezep/flutter -a [your app name]
6. git push heroku master