# Can flutter apps be deployed to AWS or self-managed servers?

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services

[Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web#deploying-to-the-web) indicate how to deploy to Google cloud:

```
 $ firebase deploy
```

Some programmers evidently have figured out [how to deploy flutter apps to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62397807/how-to-deploy-flutter-web-on-heroku).

But for a self-managed deployment -- one, for example, deployed on AWS EC2 -- documentation is scarce.

QUESTION:  if I build a flutter app, how easy is it to deploy it to AWS (or for that matter, my own cloud center)?  More generally, is there anything special I need to do to make my flutter app agnostic to cloud vendor?

If flutter is deeply tied to Google cloud services, I may have to forego this option.

Comment: It’s more common to deploy a flutter web app to AWS S3. There are a few articles about that online.